# html: place img vertically without space between

Tags: html, image

I am placing images right after each other vertically. I want them to be smushed up against each other, but I'm getting a blank line between them. How do I get rid of this line? I've tried margin=0px. I've also tried not putting them in a div.

(The image below is from the W3 editor)

```
<div>
    <img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" width="304" height="228" style = "margin:0px;">
</div>
<div>
    <img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" width="304" height="228" style = "margin:0px;">
</div>
```

Comment: This code should be fine. Try removing any extra white space between your HTML tags. Also are you sure the image doesn't contain a margin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the css property `display:block` should do the trick.  I also removed padding and margins to eliminate any other styling.  All styling should be moved to a CSS bock instead of inline.

```css
img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img border="0" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/1ff/100">
</div>
<div>
  <img border="0" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/100/1ff">
</div>
```

Comment: There's still a  blank line between them.

Comment: @user984003  Make sure your specifying `display:block` that was a late update.  There is also an example for reference.

Answer (score 1):

do this. it works if you are using table to display your images.

```
<style type="text/css">

table
{
border-collapse: collapse; /* 'cellspacing' equivalent */
}
table tr,
table td
{
padding:0;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="side1.jpg" />

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>    
<img src="side2.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

it works either for vertical and horizontal images. Just like a puzzle.
Regards.